# How do I limit jQuery dependency in Bootstrap with my project bower.json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I need to support IE8 in a web app and have to make sure jquery 1.10+ is used and not 2.0+.

My project bower.json file has dependencies listed like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap" : "~3.1.0",
    "blueimp-gallery": "~2.14.0",
    "datatables": "~1.10.0",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "~2.1.30",
    "holderjs": "~2.3.0",
    "jasmine-fixture": "~1.2.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.0.0",
    "masonry": "~3.1.5",
    "modernizr": "~2.8.1",
    "momentjs": "~2.5.1",
    "parsleyjs": "~2.0.0",
    "respond": "~1.4.2",
    "selectivizr": "~1.0.2",
    "wookmark-jquery": "~1.4.6",
    "yamm3": "1.0.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.11"
  },
```

How can I modify my bower.json dependences to 'restrict' the Bootstrap jQuery dependency it's own config file will install?

Answer (score 2):

You can't name the 1.x branch `jQuery` so just give it a different name, such as:

```
"dependencies": {
        "jquery-legacy": "jquery#1.10",
        "jquery": "~2.1.1",
}
```

Then it's up to you to include whichever one you need in your HTML, I do this:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <script src="assets/bin/lib/js/jquery-legacy/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<!--<![endif]--> 
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]>
    <script src="assets/bin/lib/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You refer to Modernize in your bower.json file so you are prepped to include different versions of jQuery on the fly:

```
Modernize.load({
    test: !document.attachEvent,
    yep: "/path/to/jquery2.js",
    nope: "/path/to/jquery1.js
});
```

The only part I'm not 100% sure on is the test (I'm on my Android phone right now, so you'll have to play around with it).

You could also use IE conditional comments to load the proper version of jQuery.

There are API differences between versions, so you might opt instead to use Zepto for IE9 and newer and jQuery for IE8. Zepto is a jquery compatible library the uses native DOM methods instead of a bunch of patches for cross browser compatibility. Either way I'd stick to one version of jQuery. Lowest common denominator all to often wins.

Answer (score 0):

You could always include jquery itself in your bower.json file:

```
"jquery": "1.10",
```

In the case that your other dependencies require a later version of jquery, bower will prompt you upon a `bower install` which version of jquery you wish to resolve to.

However, remember that it might make your project unstable, as a number of your other dependencies could make use of later versions of jquery